# Changing color in echosign

Tags: salesforce, echosign

I want to change the color of date text tag `{{_es_:signer:date}}`. Is there a way to do that? I have been on EchoSign for 4 days. I am now looking for the color changing in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what they have in their Text tagging documentation,

> "The form field formatting (font size, type, color, etc.) is determined by the format of the first ‘{‘. To ensure correct processing of Text Tags by EchoSign tag definitions should be specified in commonly occurring fonts within the document (Helvetica, Times New Roman, Arial, Verdana or Courier). Text Tag definitions are case sensitive and must be specified in lowercase text."

Or if you want to set color of the field dynamically, I guess you'll have to google about *using Acrobat Javascript*.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

{{*es*:signer:date:font(color=green}}

probably too late, but might help someone